# Precondition or preconditions?

Tags: preconditions

Guys what is the formal name PRECONDITION or PRECONDITIONS that fnc must satisfy in order to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"precondition" when it's one, "preconditions" when it's more than one?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondition ?